# Hats have a wait time?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

I've noticed something peculiar and I'm not sure if its me or if this is really happening, but it seems like some hats have a time delay before they're awarded, for instance my `Marauder` hat hasn't shown up yet, though I stole a checkmark on a question about 15m ago, other ones that seem to be delayed are `Passed Judgement` and `Reanimate`.

Is there really a lag between being awarded hats? Is this for ALL hats, or has anyone noticed any particulars that lag?

Comment: `Robocop` I think also has a bit of a delay.

Comment: Related: earlier today it was taking a while for the hats tab on the top bar to load, for me. I waited a couple minutes and it didn't show; I thought it had disappeared! But then it came back :) So delays all around!

Comment: I know that a lot of planning went into this, but as a programmer (vouching for other programmers) stuff can get buggy, and no one, regardless how much testing is put forth can quash every bug =(

Comment: The delay is too long...

Comment: The hats are added in batches... they all have a delay.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there's a delay. Similar to the badge system, you need to wait until the script runs.

Comment: Hats. It's *always* hats.

Comment: @TheFestivusUnicorn haha, we blame you for introducing this ;) Par for course Mysticial, I had a sneaky suspicion but wasn't positive. Waiting to accept.

Comment: @TheFestivusUnicorn I would've posted this as a comment instead, but I wanted to see if I could get a hat. This is my first post (on any site) since Winter Bash started. :D

Comment: @Mysticial I think its very weird though that I was awarded a `Hell, World!` immediately, but I'm still am waiting for three others? Harumph.

Comment: Oh hey! I got the Chuck Yeager hat. :D:D:D

Comment: @Mysticial Great, I wonder how, lots of people have it :P

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there's a delay, but it usually shouldn't be more than 5 minutes from the time the criteria are fulfilled until you get the hat.

However, there are some minor conditions that aren't always spelled out in the hat descriptions. For example, like most post-based hats, [Marauder](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/marauder) requires the answer to get an upvote as well.

For [Passed Judgement](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/passed-judgement) and [Reanimated](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/reanimated), note that the condition is "participate in closing/reopening/etc.", not "cast a close/reopen/etc. vote" – for the hat to be awarded, the question actually has to end up closed/reopened/etc.

Hats that depend on badges, like [Archaeologist](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/archaeologist), obviously aren't awarded until the badge is, and the badges themselves are awarded with certain delay.

[UpDo](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/updo) and [Frosty the Snowman](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/frosty-the-snowman) can only be awarded once the (UTC) day they're awarded for is over, since the condition is "all X in a day".