# How does one obtain the Yeager helmet?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

Regardless of whether or not [the man was a secret Soviet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211869/174176), this secret hat is coveted by many this year for it's sheer coolness. But what is the method of obtaining this hat?

[image: Dat hat]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Much wow](http://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Du9.jpg).

Comment: Wow. Someone just flagged this as VLC. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22881

Comment: @JoshC for good reason... these memes are all done completely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The item whose back-strap bears the hand-engraved inscription: ["J.B.M. TO J.W.H."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wesley_Hardin#Guns_and_effects) is a big hint in what must be done...

After a series of coincidences, though a committee, we've come to the hypothesis that:

> FGitW (first answer or answering quickly, with 30 minutes?) is the first requirement and having a score of at least +2 is the second requirement.

Comment: And some evidence: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212712/hats-have-a-wait-time/212713#comment684767_212713

Comment: Nope. My answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211877/212780) earned me the hat, but was **not** the first answer(by about 15 minutes).

Comment: Hmm... time to revise this hypothesis.

Comment: @GenericHolidayName Ride the [Lightning](http://i.imgur.com/VuWpUa6.jpg).

Comment: I earned it on SO and MSO, and there are no hat-related posts on SO.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212901/241749): `it has to do with comments`